# How to get response from wxWebView

Tags: c++, authentication, webview, wxwidgets

I am using `wxWebView` for `authentication` purpose in my app. I am displaying `wxWebView` instead of `login screen`. Once user enters credentials and logs in I want to take its `response` in app. How can I achieve that? How can I recieve `response` in the app?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with version 3.1.1, function [RunScript (const wxString &javascript, wxString *output=NULL)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_web_view.html#a4ca6c6e5c1c5b80dcbee725ef9fd0240) got the second parameter. You should be able to use that.